# Intellij idea does not open the project after crash

Tags: intellij-idea

Since my computer under abnormal condition was turned off, idea doesn't open my project normally (only one, which were  open at the time of shutdown).

I open a top folder, that contains all project files, but getting this in a project structure:

[image]

When I try to modify project classes, I get:

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have maven project, try re-importing as(Intellij 15.0 and above):

New > Project From Existing sources ..

Then select pom file of project not the parent directory. This will re-initialize all intellij project files(which probably have gone corrupt in your case)